# SDL_LockSurface() for multithreading

Tags: c++, sdl

Since I've been getting these errors:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
main: ../../src/xcb_io.c:178: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
```

EDIT: I also get this error sometimes:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
  after 48888 requests (48888 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I am trying to make my program multithread safe so I am putting calls to SDL_LockSurface before directly accessing the pixels.

I know that these functions access the pixels:

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface *src, SDL_Rect *srcrect, SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect);
int SDL_FillRect(SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect, Uint32 color);
```

Are there any other functions that directly access the pixels?

Comment: @nos, so what should I do? I have several threads trying to access a particular area of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL_LockSurface is used to get direct access to the pixels, it is unrelated to multi threading.

SDL only allows you to access its library function from one thread - the one that initialized the library and video subsystem, this applies to most gfx or UI libraries.

You'd have to pull out a copy of the pixels in the main thread, and distribute them to the other threads for processing. (And assemble the result back in the main thread if you need to display something again after you've processed the pixels)

Comment: You mean that I should make a copy of the `SDL_Surface` I am trying to update?

Comment: @l19 No, you have to do more than that, you have to pull out the pixels from the SDL_Surface , place them in e.g. an unsigned char array, and manipulate that. You can't operate on an SDL_Surface , a copy or not, from another thread.

Comment: when you said "and assemble the result back in the main thread" what exactly did you mean?

Comment: @l19 As you cannot use any SDL function calls in another thread, what are you going to do if you want to display the result of the work you've done in your threads ? You need some form of communicating the changes to the pixels from your threads back to the main thread, so the main thread can call some SDL function to display the new image. Doing so is too much code to explain in a comment.

Comment: Within SDL_LockSurface and SDL_UnlockSurface calls you can access SDL_Surface pixels in any way you want, including from other threads. You don't have to copy them like this accepted answer suggests.